# How Do I Send a Broadcast Request to a Node.JS server On My LAN?

Tags: node.js, ip, lan

I have a Raspberry Pi hooked up to a RGB LED strip. On the Pi, is a Node.JS server that hosts a webpage, and that webpage lets me pick a color for the LED strip. All that works.

The problem is, I want to be able to dynamically find the IP address (I don't want to do static IPs. I want to give these out to some family, and I want them to "just work" once I join them to the wifi).

What I would like to do is to have a phone app that can find the Raspberry Pi on the network. I was thinking about this, and I remembered reading about broadcast IP addresses for the LAN. I've never used them before, but seems to be what I need. The app would start up, send a specially crafted message on broadcast that says "Where's the Raspberry Pi?" and the Pi would answer "Here I am! I'm at X address!"

I've never tried to use a broadcast IP address before, so I decided to try a proof of concept. I started up a Node.JS server on my Pi that looks like this:

```
var http = require('http');

var port = 8081;

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200);
    response.end("Pong");
});
server.listen(port, function() {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Server is listening on port ' + port);
});
```

Then from my PC, `curl 192.168.1.XXX:8081` (the known IP address) and boom. Expected response.

But `curl 192.168.1.255:8081` gets me a `502` error.

From what I'm reading online, that should be the broadcast address. Is my router likely to be blocking this? Am I just doing something fundamentally wrong?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing something fundamentally wrong :)

You can not send a broadcast message using TCP/HTTP (see [Can I use broadcast or multicast for TCP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21266008/can-i-use-broadcast-or-multicast-for-tcp)) but you could send an UDP datagram (see [Send Broadcast datagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177423/send-broadcast-datagram)) instead. It should work if your router doesn't filter that kind of traffic.

Many operating systems come with a tool called `arp-scan`. You could rely on ARP (Address Resolution Protocol) and use this tool to list the IP-MAC associations on your network. You could simply use the IP that belongs to a Raspberry Pi.